# xml parsing for showing marker on google map

Tags: android

I want to show marker of diffrent color on Google map according to "`type`" in xml..means I want to diffrentiate the marker acccording to "`type`" in xml so sir how to do parsing for showing marker of diffrent color in Google map and when I click any of marker it shows a baloon in which "gallery name" will be wrriten.....   url is
http://site4demo.com/artealdiaonline/output.php?lat=-34.6394879&lng=-58.3617837kkj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML File is not that small. I recommend you to use SAX Parser for your purpose. You don't need all these information in your in-memory objects i guess because you just want to make markers on your map. With DOM, the whole XML tree will be kept in memory. I'm trying to avoid this on phones all the time due to the limited memory resources.

So you can use a SAX Parser (here is an easy example: [SAX](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/)) and then react on your row elements by creating a new Marker in your map.

Comment: Can you make your comment more specific? Your totally free how to put the markers parsed in XML into Java Objects. You could use your own Java Object "Marker" with the information needed. Be sure to use "BigDecimal" class for latitude and longtitude.

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML Parser:

1. [SAX](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/324/entry-2683-parsing-xml-in-java-part-1-sax/)
2. [DOM](http://code.dreamincode.net/forums/index.php?automodule=blog&blogid=324&showentry=2689)
3. [StAX](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/324/entry-2717-parsing-xml-in-java-part-3-stax/)